# Recurrent network (RNN) won't learn a very simple function (plots shown in the question)

Tags: python, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

So I am trying to train a simple recurrent network to detect a "burst" in an input signal. The following figure shows the input signal (blue) and the desired (classification) output of the RNN, shown in red.

[image: Then end of the sine-shaped input signal burst should be detected.]

So the output of the network should switch from 1 to 0 whenever the burst is detected and stay like with that output. The only thing that changes between the input sequences used to train the RNN is at which time step the burst occurs.

Following the Tutorial on https://github.com/MorvanZhou/PyTorch-Tutorial/blob/master/tutorial-contents/403_RNN_regressor.py, I cannot get a RNN to learn. The learned RNN always operates in a "memoryless" way, i.e., does not use memory to make its predictions, as shown in the following example behavior:

[image: The same plot as before, but this time with the output behavior of the network.]

The green line shows the predicted output of the network. **What do I do wrong in this example so that the network cannot be learned correctly?** Isn't the network task quite simple?

I'm using:

1. torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss as loss function
2. The Adam Optimizer for learning
3. A RNN with 16 internal/hidden nodes and 2 output nodes. They use the default activation function of the torch.RNN class.

The experiment has been repeated a couple of times with different random seeds, but there is little difference in the outcomes. I've used the following code:

```
import torch
import numpy, math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nofSequences = 5
maxLength = 130

# Generate training data
x_np = numpy.zeros((nofSequences,maxLength,1))
y_np = numpy.zeros((nofSequences,maxLength))
numpy.random.seed(1)
for i in range(0,nofSequences):
    startPos = numpy.random.random()*50
    for j in range(0,maxLength):
        if j>=startPos and j<startPos+10:
            x_np[i,j,0] = math.sin((j-startPos)*math.pi/10)
        else:
            x_np[i,j,0] = 0.0
        if j<startPos+10:
            y_np[i,j] = 1
        else:
            y_np[i,j] = 0


# Define the neural network
INPUT_SIZE = 1
class RNN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()

        self.rnn = torch.nn.RNN(
            input_size=INPUT_SIZE,
            hidden_size=16,     # rnn hidden unit
            num_layers=1,       # number of rnn layer
            batch_first=True,
        )
        self.out = torch.nn.Linear(16, 2)

    def forward(self, x, h_state):
        r_out, h_state = self.rnn(x, h_state)

        outs = []    # save all predictions
        for time_step in range(r_out.size(1)):    # calculate output for each time step
            outs.append(self.out(r_out[:, time_step, :]))
        return torch.stack(outs, dim=1), h_state

# Learn the network
rnn = RNN()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(rnn.parameters(), lr=0.01)
h_state = None      # for initial hidden state

x = torch.Tensor(x_np)    # shape (batch, time_step, input_size)
y = torch.Tensor(y_np).long()

torch.manual_seed(2)
numpy.random.seed(2)

for step in range(100):

    prediction, h_state = rnn(x, h_state)   # rnn output

    # !! next step is important !!
    h_state = h_state.data        # repack the hidden state, break the connection from last iteration

    loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(prediction.reshape((-1,2)),torch.autograd.Variable(y.reshape((-1,))))         # calculate loss
    optimizer.zero_grad()                   # clear gradients for this training step
    loss.backward()                         # backpropagation, compute gradients
    optimizer.step()                        # apply gradients

    errTrain = (prediction.max(2)[1].data != y).float().mean()
    print("Error Training:",errTrain.item())
```

For those who want to reproduce the experiment, the plot is drawn using the following code (using Jupyter Notebook):

```
steps = range(0,maxLength)
plotChoice = 3

plt.figure(1, figsize=(12, 5))
plt.ion()           # continuously plot

plt.plot(steps, y_np[plotChoice,:].flatten(), 'r-')
plt.plot(steps, numpy.argmax(prediction.detach().numpy()[plotChoice,:,:],axis=1), 'g-')
plt.plot(steps, x_np[plotChoice,:,0].flatten(), 'b-')

plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

Comment: On the first graph it looks as if the change in output signal comes before the change in input occurs. Shoudn't the red line indicate the output?

Comment: @muratgu Correct, I accidentally swapped the axes in the description - A non-integer classification would also not make sense. I edited the question.

Comment: The line `h_state = h_state.data` does not "break the connection from last iteration". When you call rnn(x) the `rnn.rnn` layer will be given all the `x` timesteps and will utilize the memory of the rnn as intended. In python, variable names are simply ways to point to memory and when you do `h_state = h_state.data` you simply change where the `h_state` variable points for your `__main__` context and that won't affect the training behaviour of your model.

Comment: To add to @Makis Tsantekidis's comment.  If you want to break the connection use  `h_state = copy.deepcopy(h_state.data)`

Comment: @MakisTsantekidis (and @ Jim Parker) Thanks for your hints. That part of the code is actually copied & pasted from a Tutorial (https://github.com/MorvanZhou/PyTorch-Tutorial/blob/master/tutorial-contents/403_RNN_regressor.py) - Not even sure what it does. I will try out if changing that line fines the issue tomorrow.

Comment: Does your training data include instances, where there are no bursts i.e. all the output sequences are zero?

Comment: @pbskumar Actually no. The code above is the complete code. In the part of the code where the training instances are built, it will put exactly one burst of exactly the same shape.

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there a real world application where one would throw a neural network at this kind of problem?

Comment: @fpbhb Not really. What I provided in the question is a minimally non-working example. I started with trying to tackle a real-world(tm) application, and RNN learning did not work at all for me. I then gradually simplified the task to be learned to find out what's the problem. Eventually I simplified the problem so much that the one above was left. So I knew that my original application was not too hard for RNN learning, but rather that my RNN learning attempts were faulty in some respect. The accepted answer shows what to change, and the wrong part of the code was copy&paste from a tutorial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the documentation of [tourch.nn.RNN](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.RNN), the RNN is actually an Elman network, and have the following properties seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network#Elman_networks_and_Jordan_networks).
The output of an Elman network is only dependent on the hidden state, while the hidden state is dependent on the last input and the previous hidden state.

Since we have set “h_state = h_state.data”, we actually use the hidden state of the last sequence to predict the first state of the new sequence, which will result in an output heavily dependent on the last output of the previous sequence (which was 0). The Elman network can’t separate if we are in the beginning of the sequence or at the end, it only "sees" the state and last input.

To fix this we can insted set “h_state = None”.
Now every new sequence start with an empty state. This result in the following prediction (where green line again shows the prediction).[image]
Now we start off at 1, but quickly dips down to 0 before the puls push it back up again.
The Elman network can account for some time dependency, but it is not good at remembering long term dependencies, and converge towards an "most common output" for that input.

So to fix this problem, I suggest using a network which is well known for handling long term dependencies well, namely the Long short-term memory (LSTM) rnn, for more information see [torch.nn.LSTM](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.LSTM). Keep "h_state = None" and change torch.nn.RNN to torch.nn.LSTM.

for complete code and plot see below

```
import torch
import numpy, math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nofSequences = 5
maxLength = 130

# Generate training data
x_np = numpy.zeros((nofSequences,maxLength,1))
y_np = numpy.zeros((nofSequences,maxLength))
numpy.random.seed(1)
for i in range(0,nofSequences):
    startPos = numpy.random.random()*50
    for j in range(0,maxLength):
        if j>=startPos and j<startPos+10:
            x_np[i,j,0] = math.sin((j-startPos)*math.pi/10)
        else:
            x_np[i,j,0] = 0.0
        if j<startPos+10:
            y_np[i,j] = 1
        else:
            y_np[i,j] = 0


# Define the neural network
INPUT_SIZE = 1
class RNN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()

        self.rnn = torch.nn.LSTM(
            input_size=INPUT_SIZE,
            hidden_size=16,     # rnn hidden unit
            num_layers=1,       # number of rnn layer
            batch_first=True,
        )
        self.out = torch.nn.Linear(16, 2)

    def forward(self, x, h_state):
        r_out, h_state = self.rnn(x, h_state)

        outs = []    # save all predictions
        for time_step in range(r_out.size(1)):    # calculate output for each time step
            outs.append(self.out(r_out[:, time_step, :]))
        return torch.stack(outs, dim=1), h_state

# Learn the network
rnn = RNN()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(rnn.parameters(), lr=0.01)
h_state = None      # for initial hidden state

x = torch.Tensor(x_np)    # shape (batch, time_step, input_size)
y = torch.Tensor(y_np).long()

torch.manual_seed(2)
numpy.random.seed(2)

for step in range(100):

    prediction, h_state = rnn(x, h_state)   # rnn output

    # !! next step is important !!
    h_state = None        

    loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(prediction.reshape((-1,2)),torch.autograd.Variable(y.reshape((-1,))))         # calculate loss
    optimizer.zero_grad()                   # clear gradients for this training step
    loss.backward()                         # backpropagation, compute gradients
    optimizer.step()                        # apply gradients

    errTrain = (prediction.max(2)[1].data != y).float().mean()
    print("Error Training:",errTrain.item())


###############################################################################
steps = range(0,maxLength)
plotChoice = 3

plt.figure(1, figsize=(12, 5))
plt.ion()           # continuously plot

plt.plot(steps, y_np[plotChoice,:].flatten(), 'r-')
plt.plot(steps, numpy.argmax(prediction.detach().numpy()[plotChoice,:,:],axis=1), 'g-')
plt.plot(steps, x_np[plotChoice,:,0].flatten(), 'b-')

plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

[image]